# Adding enemy by time interval? and not by coordinate. Html5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to add another enemy. I have this one zombie that pretty much just drops from the sky. Rather than keep adding negative coordinates to drop I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this?

```
new Zombie1({      
      position: {
        x: 4000,
        y: -9500
      },
      velocity: {
        x: -1,
        y: 0
      },
      distance: {
        limit: 7,
        traveled: 0
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to spawn enemies at 1000 milliseconds:

```
setInterval(() => {
   new Zombie(...)
}, 1000)
```

When finished(e.g. level is ended), you can use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) to stop instantiating new zombies. For having random positions you can use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
var zombieInterval

function startLevel(){
    setInterval(() => {
       new Zombie(...)
    }, 1000)
}

function endLevel(){
    clearInterval(zombieInterval)
}
```